# asp.net mvc TDD emulate many concurrent users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tdd

I am writing an MVC2 asp.net web app.  I would like to have some performance tests within the test project, where I emulate hundreds of users all accessing the database layer at the same time.  Is there a way that I can write a test that will make lots of concurrent calls to different controllers?  Do I need to spawn lots of threads to make the multiuser aspect truly concurrent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you using a specific tool for performing load tests instead of writing this logic manually by spawning new threads. For example if you have the full version of Visual Studio you could create web tests which represent different user scenarios and then execute those scenarios in a [load test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182594.aspx). Another useful tool is [Apache JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need multiple threads to do a full integration testing simulating concurrent user behavior.
You can either create spawn threads yourself or use something Parallel.Foreach() for a  slightly more convenient way.

However these shouldn't be part of your unit test suite because they're a different kind of test than unit tests. Best to not mix them with your regular unit tests.